# Is there any difference between x += 1 and x = x + 1 in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

In c#, is there any difference (semantics, efficiency, etc.) between writing `x = x + 1` and `x += 1`? Is it compiled to the same thing? Or optimized in some way?

For me, looks like it should be the same or `+=` should be "optimized" as `x = x + ...`, but is it?

Comment: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxASwDYB8ACAmARgFgAoHAZgAJ9KBhSgb1MpeqpwBZKBZACgEpGzViLQA7GAG0AupQDmlALyNKBAL4BuYSJbadcyQAZZAamUEtJHaz0icBAJy85/SyLV7brCtS4A5ASEra0pxKVkFZQZVTS9dYOsDYyV5I1NVNxD7JxdMlg8SUjUgA= is one example.

Comment: @dratenik C# does not allow compound operators to be overloaded, they will just refer to the non-compound version. MSIL allows it, I'm not sure if C# will recognize it though

Comment: @mjwill Interesting, but I'd love to know if there was any practical difference between `ldelema  ldind` and `ldelem`, looking at the ASM it's probably only a difference for multithreading, where you should be interlocking anyway

Comment: You'd need to benchmark to be sure @Charlieface.

Comment: Declare x as *byte* and you'll easily notice the difference.  One of the less pretty quirks of C#.  Otherwise just syntax, IL does not have a += operator so the C# compiler has to use +.

Comment: Given the duplicate does not appear to cover either of the scenarios mentioned in the comments here, someone may wish to add an answer / comment to the duplicate.